# Two convergent sequences have a common subsequence?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $(x_n )_{n\in\mathbb N}$   and $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$   are two sequences converging to zero, monotonically. And $nx_n$ and $ny_n$ are bounded. Then can we find a subsequence of each, $x_{n_j}{n_j}$ and $y_{n_k}n_k$, respectively, such that $x_{n_j}n_j$ and $y_{n_k}n_k$ have the same limit?

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily. Consider $x_{n}=\frac{1}{n}$ and $y_{n}=\frac{2}{n}$ which monotonically tend to $0$ and $nx_{n}=1$ and $ny_{n}=2$. The same will happen for subsequences.

Comment: You're welcome.